# parse cucumber scenario outline into individual scenarios

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm wanting to know the easiest way to parse through an existing scenario outline and break it into individual scenarios? I'm wanting to do this because certain scenario outlines have become too complicated and conveluded, and thus they need to be broken down. Is there some way to hack Cucumber to be able to do this without even having to run the scenario outline? Any help would be much appreciated! I could MANUALLY break the scenario outlines down, but it would take many hours whereas some sort of parser could do so in minutes.

I was thinking of writing my own parser, but I know Cucumber (for ruby) likely already just does that. Making my own parser from scratch seems silly if the parser may already exist in Cucumber. I'm not sure where in Cucumber this sort of stuff would live though

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin